# How to display Hello when a button is clicked

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Requires method overloading, but I don't need to accept parameters, how can I make it work?

```
public IActionResult SlMas()
            {
                return View();
            }
            [HttpPost]
            public string SlMas()
            {
                    return "hello";
            }
    
    
    
    @{
        ViewData["Title"] = "SlMas";
    }
    
    <form method="post">
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Проверить" />
        </p>
    </form>
```

Comment: so you are saying the post action is not being hit when you place a break point?

Comment: Requires method SlMas overloading, but I don't need to accept parameters

Comment: Isn't a Get then what you need ? A Post means you're creating something

Comment: You can't have two methods in the same class in C# that only differ by their return type. One possible way of resolving this would be to rename the post method and add a `[Route("/some-url")]` attribute to give it the URL it would have had had you not needed to rename it.

Comment: You still did not answer the question:  When you place a break point in the POST Action it is not being called when you click on the submit button?

Comment: I cannot put a breakpoint, it gives an error that the method needs to be reloaded

Comment: What if you made the Post method take a nullable parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Method overloading is multiple methods can have the **same name** with **different parameters**.

If you do not want parameters in HttpPost SlMas method,you must change the name.

For your scenario,you could use `ActionName` attribute when you want to alias the name of the Action method:

```
public IActionResult SlMas()
{
    return View();
}
[HttpPost, ActionName("SlMas")]
public string Hello()
{
    return "hello";
}
```

Besides,as @Martin Costello said,you could also use `Route` attribute:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("/TheSameWithYourHttpGetUrl")]
public string Hello()
{
    return "hello";
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
public IActionResult SlMas()
            {
                return View();
            }
            [HttpPost]
            public string SlMas(int a)
            {
                    return "hello";
            }
```

you can do something like this however, I would not recommend this. You should either tackle this through front end or send something useful in the post request.